# How do I filter out XSLT report results by keyword?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XSLT that pulls back a series of medication names(@clinical-name). I'd like to filter out a specific medication name, Claritin, from my results.

I'm relatively new to XSLT coding, so I've not tried much beyond adding in a

```
<xsl:template match="n:medication-order">
    <div class="ddemrcontentitem ddremovable" style="margin-left: 1em; padding-left:1em; text-indent:-1em;">
        <xsl:attribute name="dd:entityid">
            <xsl:value-of select="@order-id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="dd:contenttype">
            <xsl:text>MEDICATIONS</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="@clinical-name"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You're missing a [mcve].

Comment: Possibly adding in a template `<xsl:template match="n:medication-order[@clinical-name='Claritin']" />` would work, but as zx485 mentions, we would need to see you input XML and more of your XSLT to be sure. Thanks!

Comment: "Filter out' is ambiguous, you need to say whether you want the things that match "Claritin", or those that don't.

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity! What I mean is that I want everything except Claritin to display.